# How can I make text appear on an image?

Tags: html, image, text, hover

Is there a way to make a text appear on an embed image?

[That text appears when the cursor hovers over the image]

Comment: do you have any html or css code for this

Answer (score 0):

https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

You can use the :hover selector in the css to make your text appear when the mouse hovers over the image

Answer (score 0):

Without any examples, yes. Your image and text should be different entities, in that CSS should be able to reference them distinctly. Then you can just do something like this.

```
#your-text-elements-id:hover {
    visibility: "visible"
}

#your-text-elements-id {
    visibility: "hidden"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code to make text appear on cursor hover the image

```css
.texthover {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    position:relative;}

.texthover .overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:25%;
    height:50%;
    padding:10px;
    display:none;
}
.texthover:hover .overlay {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="texthover"><br />
 <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/U2R2BfwOe-ZiqI1gSgmTpZPDkWBNacaO8_HZkKkVee-wHlHV505gmX91DZnq-dYbzY96" height="50%" width="50%"/>
<div class="overlay"><br />
 <h1>Ashok Purohit</h1></div>
</div>
```